# Unable to add a picture in xamarin.forms.

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-8.1-oreo

```
Image codeImage = new Image
            {
                Source = "code.jpg",
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };
            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    codeImage
                },
                HeightRequest = 1500
            };
```

I have the image in the default location in the project. I've even tried right-clicking my project going to add then making a new default image then replacing that image with the image i want to use. Hell I've tried just using the default image that gets built when adding new image going into paint drawing a few squiggly lines and then trying it again and still NOTHING.

Comment: where specifically did you place the image, and what is it's build action set to?

Comment: @Jason; The exact location == C:\Users\clayt\source\repos\helloWorld\helloWorld\helloWorld\code.jpg 
you mention action? Do i need an action to display shouldn't it display automatically?

Comment: I mean in context of your project - Android images should be in Resources/Drawable with a build action of AndroidResource.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images

Comment: @Jason; ok I think I am getting a little further. I am trying a combination of putting my picture in the drawable folder and the drawable-hdi folders. I've tried building code.jpg via "androidresource" and "content". I've tried switching the Source = "code.jpg" to Source = @"C:\Users\clayt\source\repos\helloWorld\helloWorld\helloWorld.Android\Resources\drawable\code.jpg". However still not working.

Comment: If you use a Label instead, does that show?  If not, then that indicates a problem with your layout, not the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to Content like this:

```
Image codeImage = new Image
{
    Source = "code.jpg",
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
};
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        codeImage
    },
    HeightRequest = 1500
};
// If the above isn't working in itself, this will help as final closure:
Content = stackLayout;
```

Comment: So it should not be contained within Children?

Comment: It's all fine as it is, but you need to add the final result to Content.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say add final result to "Content". you said Content = stackLayout; my "codeImage" IS in stackLayout which = Content for it is contained in Children and Children is a placeholder? for the items IN stackLayout which IS Content. idk....

Comment: Well, it actually depends on the proper context and if it's not working for you, then Content would help you because I assume that the StackLayout will be on a ContentPage, and the magic keyword for that is Content. Of course, it's possible that something else might be wrong like the way you added the picture: In my experience, Xamarin doesn't like when I drag and drop images from the desktop, I need to right-click on folders to Add Existing Items..

Comment: Anderson , I've brute forced through so many different options... I have tried having the picture being "Content" rather than "androidResource" etc. There is probably just something that i'm overlooking. I'm going to ask my classmates and see if they got it to work. I'll update here If i get it to work. Adding a picture to the content should not be this difficult. This is super beginner stuff. This is quite literally a hello world project level stuff :D